# any Open source projects in .NET for medical diagnosis & data mining

Tags: .net, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I can't find any open source projects in .NET/C# for medical diagnosis & data mining. Do any such projects exist?

Comment: Have you tried to search on github or other site like it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with such a project and I doubt if it exists (as it is quite specific). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014957/java-open-source-projects-for-medical-diagnose-data-mining) is a similar question (+ answer) though regarding an open source Java medical diagnosis program.

Comment: question tells about .NET not java...

Comment: Correct, but I doubt that an open source .NET/C# medical diagnosis package exists, therefore I refer to a similar project which does exist and which be of some help. I updated my post to reflect these thoughts.

Comment: Ok..Thanks...well, can you suggest me what algorithm can be used for such types proj.???

Comment: [This](http://www.openclinical.org/dss.html) website has a nice overview of the history of early medical diagnosis systems and links to current approaches.

Comment: thanx buddy...it will be helpful :)